# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, cxf

```
    Error Log
    11:24:27,620 WARNING [org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] (MSC service thread 1-1) Invalid JavaBean property 'serviceBeans' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setServiceBeans(java.lang.Object[])]: [public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.setServiceBeans(java.util.List)]
    11:24:27,764 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1) org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://apache.org/cxf/binding/jaxrs registered.

    11:24:27,768 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:91)

    11:24:27,772 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.createBindingInfo(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:136)

    11:24:27,776 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.createEndpointInfo(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:116)

    11:24:27,779 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.createEndpoint(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:162)

    11:24:27,783 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:83)

    11:24:27,786 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    11:24:27,792 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

    11:24:27,795 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

    11:24:27,798 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

    11:24:27,800 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536)

    11:24:27,804 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)

    11:24:27,808 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)

    11:24:27,813 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)

    11:24:27,816 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)

    11:24:27,820 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)

    11:24:27,823 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)

    11:24:27,827 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)

    11:24:27,831 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)

    11:24:27,833 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)

    11:24:27,836 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)

    11:24:27,840 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)

    11:24:27,843 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)

    11:24:27,845 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)

    11:24:27,847 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)

    11:24:27,851 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368)

    11:24:27,853 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821)

    11:24:27,855 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70)

    11:24:27,857 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)

    11:24:27,859 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)

    11:24:27,860 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)

    11:24:27,862 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

    11:24:27,865 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

    11:24:27,877 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Setting the server's publish address to be /
    11:24:27,902 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6ac18c: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationListener,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory,jacksonProvider,myService,serviceImpl,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
    11:24:27,933 SEVERE [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_18]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_18]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:112) [cxf-bundle-2.2.3.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_18]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_18]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_18]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:122) [cxf-bundle-2.2.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:103) [cxf-bundle-2.2.3.jar:]
        ... 27 more

    11:24:28,007 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jaxws]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423) [spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_18]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_18]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:112) [cxf-bundle-2.2.3.jar:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_18]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_18]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_18]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_18]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409) [spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:122) [cxf-bundle-2.2.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:103) [cxf-bundle-2.2.3.jar:]
        ... 27 more

    11:24:28,117 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
    11:24:28,119 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/jaxws] startup failed due to previous errors
    11:24:28,131 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jaxws]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    11:24:28,137 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) registering web context: /jaxws
    11:24:28,141 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss AS 7.0.2.Final "Arc" started (with errors) in 22181ms - Started 224 of 284 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 57 services are passive or on-demand)
    11:24:28,199 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployed "jaxws.war"
```

*Bean.xml*

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

        <!-- define the jackson provider for JAXB/JSON support --> 
        <bean id="jacksonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />

        <jaxrs:server id="myService" address="/">
            <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                <ref bean="serviceImpl" />
            </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <jaxrs:providers>
                <ref bean='jacksonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
        </jaxrs:server>

        <bean id="serviceImpl" class="com.rs.UserServiceImpl" />

        <security:http>
            <security:http-basic></security:http-basic>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:http>

        <security:authentication-manager  alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>            
                <security:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>   
    </beans>
```

*web.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>        
            <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>        
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app> 

I am working on apache cxf and developing a rest web service example
```

I got above error in my program. Also posted bean.xml and web.xml
    Please help regarding the error, I am using maven and spring I just want to authenticate a user.

Comment: give me any suggestion pl z

Comment: any reply plz give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is

```
org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://apache.org/cxf/binding/jaxrs registered.
```

This related question might help you find a solution:
[CXF JAX-RS is causing BusException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872202/cxf-jax-rs-is-causing-busexception)